# How do i insert into a MySQL db from a file?

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc

My table has around 190 fields. Out of which **only 30 cannot be null**. And around 7k rows are to be inserted.

I am using JDBC. Is there anyway of inputting all these directly from a text file in a single INSERT instead of doing an INSERT statement 7k times.

Comment: maybe you can use import in MySQL check this out http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/import-mysql-dumpfile-sql-datafile-into-my-database/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a query itself, you can use `LOAD DATA INFILE`. It is a very fast method of importing a file. However, the file has to be properly formatted.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html